# Interact with Embedded Google Apps Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to use Javascript to interact with an google spreadsheet when embedded in a html website?

I am looking to do some of the following operations:

- Switch Worksheets
- Read the formula (or value) of a cell / active cell
- Set the value of a cell / active cell
- Adjust formatting or some of the other features available when using Google Scripts inside the spreadsheet application.

I know google has a great app engine that works inside google docs but I would like to be able to interact with the spreadsheet via javascript when it is embedded inside an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this

1. Use the JavaScript API for Spreadsheets ( https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js )
2. Write a Google Apps Script, deploy it as a web app and make AJAX/REST calls from your JavaScript. See Content Service to see how this can be done using GAS ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content )